# Zooming text using DirectWrite

Tags: windows, directx, zooming, direct2d, directwrite

Does anyone know how to implement text zooming using DirectWrite/Direct2D APIs? I need smooth high-precision zooming in/out of large bodies of text, but couldn't find any demos/samples.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the Transform on the `ID2D1RenderTarget`.